# Cisco "show archive config diff" displays crypto pki

Tags: cisco, cli

I have a Cisco WS-C3560G-24PS. We're going to make some changes to it, so I ran the command `show archive config diff` to make sure everything is fine if we need to revert the changes.

My problem is that when I run that command it gives me the following that is in my running config:

```
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-##########
 +certificate self-signed 01 nvram:IOS-Self-Sig#1.cer
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-##########
 -certificate self-signed 01
  lots and lots of numbers
```

After checking with my manager, he confirmed that we added some certificates to the switch and I can save the running config. I ran the command `copy system:running-config nvram:startup-config` and ran the `show archive config diff` again and it shows the same thing. Cisco isn't my strong suite, so I'm not sure if this is normal behavior with certificates on a Cisco device or not. Is this something I need to worry about?

Comment: Try a simpler command:  "write memory"   and see if that clears it up.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too and it's displaying the same message. I'm assuming this has something to do with Crypto and perhaps is generated on boot up. But I don't know enough about Cisco to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `archive config` command to write a new copy of the config to the archive. That should clear up your diffs.